# Typeorm converting date to +3 hours?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, date, typeorm

I trying get the real hour of a register as do in my postgresSQL, when I access the DB I see

[DB Register with Date Today, 11:30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsefi.png)

When I do my request

```
const tomorrow = moment().add(1, 'days');
const today = moment().startOf('day');
return this.ormRepository.find({
  where: {
    startHour: MoreThanOrEqual(today),
    endHour: LessThanOrEqual(tomorrow),
  },
  order: { startHour: 'ASC' },

  join: {
    alias: 'reserves',
    leftJoinAndSelect: {
      table: 'reserves.table',
    },
  },
});
```

}

with typeorm to view the postgres register I see a different hour Today, 14:30.

[Today 14:30 Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIVlV.png)

I don't know whats happening and can't found it in any documentation, in production its all ok, the problem is in my dev and I can't found any solution.

I tested my code in a docker container and the date is coming right (Today, 11:30)

Update: I temporaly solved the problem changing my computer time to UTC

Answer (score 0):

What type of field in postgres you setup ? timestamptz ?

In postgres if you execute select Date() you received UTC

[image]

Comment: Its timestamp (timestamp without time zone)

Comment: timestamptz in progress is UTC.
Check here https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/entities.md#column-types-for-postgres

Additionally you can check what will return if you use ISODate